# Insert values in a table based on values from a view and another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and a view with this structure ( all columns are strings ):

```
first_table -> 1 column
second_table -> 3 columns
view -> 1 column
```

In all of them i have a column called system.First table don't have the latest systems like the view does.
So what i'm trying to do is to insert into the first_table all systems from the view that are not already inserted
in the table and also to ignore the ones that are in the second table.

Example :

```
Fist Table :     View:         Second table:

System 1         System 1      System 2 
                 System 2      System 3
                 System 3
                 System 4
                 System 5
```

I want the first_table to look like this :

```
System 1
System 4
System 5
```

Until now i tried something like this :

```
INSERT ignore INTO first_table
SELECT SYSTEM
  FROM view
where System !="" GROUP BY System
```

and another :

```
INSERT ignore INTO first_table
    SELECT System
        FROM view
        WHERE System !="" GROUP BY System  and  NOT EXISTS (SELECT System
                              FROM view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track using `NOT EXISTS`. But you have to correlate the subquery (For which system no row must exist?) and use two of them, one for each table.

```
INSERT INTO `first table`
            (system)
            SELECT v.system
                   FROM `view` v
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM `first table` t1
                                            WHERE t1.system = v.system)
                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                FROM `second table` t2
                                                WHERE t2.system = v.system);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bed5e34f61851541f60f1f50eb2b39ad)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0fd34/6/0)

```
SELECT TFinal.S 
FROM (
 SELECT S FROM T3 WHERE S NOT IN (SELECT S FROM T2) 
) AS TFinal
WHERE TFinal.S NOT IN (SELECT S FROM T1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like the below. The idea is to do a union on T2 and T1 and minus on T3. Please note this is for reference only. Rewrite as needed:

```
INSERT INTO T1  select S from T3 where T3.S NOT IN (SELECT S from T2 UNION select S from T1);
```